# Unable to deploy infra on azure while using another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-resource-manager

I work with 2 subscriptions, before this I only implemented on one of them, but now I need to implement on the second one which is the production unit.
In Azure Devops I have added the service connection name for the `armServiceConnection`.

I think this can be solved by adding a role assignment with the Contributor roles to the resource group, but how to add a "subscription" as "name", I can only find emails and some groups.

**Additional logs:**

```
Error: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '8347968f-b300-4f88-8354-2688f6abeeda' with object id '8347968f-b300-4f88-8354-2688f6abeeda' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/19d0884f-4732-4c3b-91ea-0d78b603bec0/resourcegroups/rg-opendata-prd' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
│ 
│   with data.azurerm_resource_group.rg,
│   on main.tf line 3, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│    3: data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
│ 
╵
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to service connection details you can then click and go to your service principal:

[image]

From that place you can easily add proper permissions.

Comment: I went there and added my account as an owner but I still get the same error.

Comment: You should give permissions for account `{org-name}-{project-name}-{guid}`.

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding the right account you mentioned. Thanks